# getElementById equivalent in Silverlight + XAML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, getelementbyid

I am developing a Windows Phone app. There is an element in an [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) file, and I want to reference it in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29). Is there any equivalent of `getElementById` used in JavaScript?

For example,
there are two text strings, one has `Name` equal to `1` and another equal to `2`. User gives string input either `1` or `2`, accordingly the text is highlighted. Now, I want to convert this string input from user into reference, how that can be done ?

Answer (score 2):

To find the element in the page tree based on a string use [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598120%28vs.95%29) method

Comment: sorry, probably i was not clear, i have edited my question, kindly tell me if you have a solution.